# Does SQL SERVER 2014 queues the incoming request in a locked table?

Tags: sql-server

```
USE [ProjectDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[generateTransRefNo]    Script Date: 9/9/2017 7:19:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[generateTransRefNo]

(

    @year varchar(max),
    @txrefno varchar(max) output
)

AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @seq varchar(max)
set @seq = '00000000'
select @txrefno = sequence from TBSEQUENCE WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) where year =@year
if(@txrefno='' or @txrefno is null)
begin
insert into TBSEQUENCE values (substring(cast(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) as varchar),3,4),1,'YR')
end
select @txrefno = concat(year,SUBSTRING('00000000',1,8- len(sequence)),sequence) from TBSEQUENCE where year =@year
update TBSEQUENCE set sequence = sequence+1 where year=@year
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END 
select @txrefno
```

Say I have this stored procedure that gets the latest sequence from tbsequence then update it

The application is java using hibernate to access the database which is deployed already that I cannot access.

**Will this hold the incoming requests while the current request is still up or cancel them and returns nothing?**

Comment: Only one session can hold a `TABLOCK`. One session will get the lock and proceed, the others will wait until the lock becomes available again (or until `LOCK_TIMEOUT` milliseconds have passed, but by default the wait is infinite). If you hit the command timeout, though (30 seconds by default) the request will be cancelled client side.

Comment: why can't you use identity or inbuilt sequence

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. I think I'm okay with this.

Comment: @TheGameiswar The sequence is used by different tables so I think identity is not the solution. I don't know what is inbuilt sequence

Comment: I think TABLOCK is overkill since row-locking is the default. For a roll-your-own sequence in a high-concurrency workload, I'd ditch the SELECT and instead UPDATE with a HOLDLOCK hint with `SET @sequence = sequence = sequence + 1' and then `INSERT` if no rows were updated. That will reduce the number of queries in the common case where a row for the specified year exists.